# Interchanging the order of integration (related to resolvent kernel)

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, partial-differential-equations

I was reading a chapter related to resolvent kernel, and there was one step that I don't quite understand.

> Assuming $k(t,s)$ and $g(t)$ are continouous,$\int^t_0k(t,s)\int^s_0k(s,\tau)g(\tau)d\tau ds = \int^t_0 \int^t_\tau k(t,s)k(s,\tau)ds\space g(\tau) d\tau$

How did they get the order of integration interchanged?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There's something off about the RHS (are you sure about the integration limits?)

Comment: @AhmedHussein I just checked it. I think that's what written there.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_integration_(calculus)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem